# How to fix numpy TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, google-colaboratory

I have been trying to implement the polynomial regression model in python on spyder IDE , everything works good and at the end when I try to add the arrange function from numpy it gives me the following error !!

```
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

dataset = pd.read_csv("Position_Salaries.csv")
X = dataset.iloc[:, 1:2]
y = dataset.iloc[:, 2]

#fitting the linear regression model
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
lin_reg = LinearRegression()
lin_reg.fit(X,y)

#fitting the polynomial linear Regression
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
poly_reg = PolynomialFeatures(degree = 4)
X_poly = poly_reg.fit_transform(X)
lin_reg2 = LinearRegression()
lin_reg2.fit(X_poly,y)

#visualising the linear regression results
plt.scatter(X,y ,color = 'red')
plt.plot(X,lin_reg.predict(X), color='blue')
plt.title('linear regression model')
plt.xlabel('positive level')
plt.ylabel('salary')
plt.show()

#the code doesnt work here on this np.arrange linee !!!
#visualisng the polynomial results
X_grid = np.arange(min(X),max(X), 0.1)
X_grid = X_grid.reshape((len(X_grid), 1))
plt.scatter(X,y ,color = 'red')
plt.plot(X_grid,lin_reg2.predict( poly_reg.fit_transform(X_grid)), color='blue')
plt.title('linear regression model')
plt.xlabel('positive level')
plt.ylabel('salary')
plt.show()
```

it should run and execute without any error !

Error Traceback:-

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-24-428026f3698c> in <module>()
----> 1 x_grid = np.arange(min(x),max(x),0.1)
      2 print(x_grid, x)
      3 x_grid = x_grid.reshape((len(x_grid),1))
      4 
      5 plt.scatter(x, y, color = 'red')

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

Comment: You should show the stacktrace with your error as well.

Comment: error means it try to substract two strings -  like `"123" - "12"`. Maybe you forgot convert strings with numbers to integers. If there are NaN values in column then `read_csv()` may not convert strings to integers automatically.

Comment: but there are no NAN values .. there are two columns and all have integers from 1-10 and 45k to 100k.

Comment: With a dataframe of two columns, what do you expect `min(X)` to produce?  What **does** it do?

Answer (score 2):

If this error occurs in:

```
np.arange(min(X),max(X), 0.1)
```

it must be because `min(X)` and `max(X)` are strings.

```
In [385]: np.arange('123','125')                                                                                
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-385-0a55b396a7c3> in <module>
----> 1 np.arange('123','125')

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

Since `X` is a `pandas` object (dataframe or series?) this isn't too surprising.  `pandas` freely uses object dtype when it can't use a number (and doesn't use numpy string dtype):

```
X = dataset.iloc[:, 1:2]
```

`np.arange(np.array('123'),np.array('125'))` produces a different error, about 'U3' dtypes.

The fact that the LinearRegresion calls work with this `X` is a little puzzling, but I don't know how it sanitizes its inputs.

In any case, I'd check `min(X)` before the `arange` call, looking at its value and type.  If it is a string, then explore the `X` in greater detail.

---

In a comment you say: `there are two columns and all have integers from 1-10 and 45k to 100k.`  Is that '45k' an integer, or a string?

---

Let's do a test on a dummy dataframe:

```
In [392]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1,45000],[2,46000],[3,47000]], columns=('A','B'))                                 
In [393]: df                                                                                                    
Out[393]: 
   A      B
0  1  45000
1  2  46000
2  3  47000
In [394]: min(df)                                                                                               
Out[394]: 'A'
In [395]: max(df)                                                                                               
Out[395]: 'B'
```

`min` and `max` produce strings - derived from the column names.

In contrast the `fit` functions are probably working with the array values of the dataframe:

```
In [397]: df.to_numpy()                                                                                         
Out[397]: 
array([[    1, 45000],
       [    2, 46000],
       [    3, 47000]])
```

Don't assume things should work!  Test, debug, print suspect values.

---

`min/max` are the python functions.  The numpy ones operate in a dataframe sensitive way -

```
In [399]: np.min(df)      # delegates to df.min()                                                                                      
Out[399]: 
A        1
B    45000
dtype: int64
In [400]: np.max(df)                                                                                            
Out[400]: 
A        3
B    47000
dtype: int64
```

though those aren't appropriate inputs to `arange` either.

What exactly do you intend to produce with this `arange` call?

`arange` on the range of **one column** of the dataframe works:

```
In [405]: np.arange(np.min(df['A']), np.max(df['A']),.1)                                                        
Out[405]: 
array([1. , 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9, 2. , 2.1, 2.2,
       2.3, 2.4, 2.5, 2.6, 2.7, 2.8, 2.9])
```

Comment: thankyou very much for your time and effort paul :)

Answer (score 1):

Try out this code. This worked for me as I am also doing the Udemy lecture.

```
X_grid = np.arange(min(X ['Level']), max(X['Level']), 0.01, dtype= float) 
X_grid = X_grid.reshape((len(X_grid), 1))

#plotting
plt.scatter(X,y, color = 'red')
plt.plot(X,lin_reg2.predict(poly_reg.fit_transform(X)), color = 'blue') ``
plt.title('Truth or Bluff (Polynomial Regression)')
plt.xlabel('Position Level')
plt.ylabel('Salary')
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to make sure whatever your inputs are have the correct type. It seems to me the types for the op are both `str`. Maybe try to transform them into floats by `float(x)` or some similar functions?

Answer (score 0):

You should check what is in X and y. They are probably series objects containing strings. What you want is to extract the value in X and y and convert them to floats/ints before doing anything with them.

Something like:

```
X = dataset.iloc[:, 1:2].astype(float)
y = dataset.iloc[:, 2].astype(float)
```

Comment: @haroonkhan Edit your post and show the error when you tried this.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
x = dataset.iloc[:, 1:2].values

y = dataset.iloc[:, -1:].values
```

Because you only have to accept numerical values in `x` and `y`.

Using `dataset.iloc[].values` means it will **not** include the `Level` and `Salary` name in `x` and `y` dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Replace,

```py
X = dataset.iloc[:, 1:2] and y = dataset.iloc[:, 2]
```

With,

```
X = dataset.iloc[:, 1:2].values and y = dataset.iloc[:, 2].values
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are getting the values from the dataset. Remember it is:

```
x = dataset.iloc[:, 1:-1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, -1].values
```

not:

```
x = dataset.iloc[:, 1:-1]
y = dataset.iloc[:, -1]
```

Without `".values"` you get strings `("str")` that your error message is showing

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
X_grid = np.arange(float(min(X ['Level'])), float(max(X['Level'])), 0.01, dtype= float)
```